# I'm looking to develop a simple two player online turn based game using ruby on rails. Any tips

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiplayer

I am looking to knock off a quickie rails app that will allow two players to take turns and get feedback after each turn - approximately 10 rounds of turns so there are no issues with long lived connections.

I want to use rails because I know it reasonably well, have hosting already set up and have my tools installed.

Do you have any advice on plugins, libraries or tutorials to help out with the communication between players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This links may be helpful:
http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/
http://github.com/socky/socky-server-ruby

Comment: Juggernaut might be useful.  I don't need to handle a multitude of simultaneous connections for indefinite periods of time so it may be a bit of overkill and an extra deployment monitoring headache but I'm considering it.  Socky is based on websockets which has rather unrealistic browser restrictions which rules it out.  Maybe in a few years...

Comment: Zed Shaw's "Death to WebSockets" Note in Mongrel2 documentation: http://mongrel2.org/doc/tip/docs/manual/book.wiki#x1-550005.1.3

Comment: Actually Socky has built-in support for flash fallback, which gives it full support on nearly every device. So no - it's not "in few years" but "right now" :)

Answer (score 1):

Socky will be probably better because it's ruby(juggernaut is now node.js based) and don't require redis. Also it has flash fallback for browsers without websocket implementation so it cover most of devices.